# Why doesn't my pull-up work on S-35770 I2C counter IC?

Tags: resistors, i2c, counter, pullup, breakout

I designed the following PCB from the schematic below to make a breakout for an I2C counter IC, datasheet is [here](https://www.ablic.com/en/doc/datasheet/counter_ic/S35770_I_E.pdf).

However my RST pin doesn't go up and the IC stays in reset state. I'm feeding 3.3V to VCC. A multimeter is showing 0.29V on the RST pin. I probed also with the multimeter and the 10k resistance is there from VCC to RST PIN.

I added another normal 10k resistor from my breadboard to the RST pin and the pin went up and it's working after that. Any idea why my board 10k resistor is not working?

[image: S-35770 I2C Binary Counter SCH] [image: S-35770 I2C Binary Counter PCB]

Comment: Are you sure that you placed the IC correctly, as in, is pin 1 of the IC on pin 1 of the board?

Comment: yes, otherwise I2C would not work and it's working fine after adding the external pull-up.

Comment: @binaryOps20 that's why it requires an external pull-up

Comment: I read the whole datasheet. I'm using a lab bench power supply, I can't check the ripple as I don't have an oscilloscope, but it's a new power supply, I doubt that it would be a problem as it works fine with the external 10k pullup on the same pin.

Comment: You put the other pull-up resistor parallel to the one on the board? Maybe 10k is too weak to pull it up and 5k (10k || 10k) does the trick.

Comment: I took the 10k from their example application circuit in the datasheet. How to calculate the pullup resistor with datasheet information? Is there any possibility of the capacitor doing something with the pullup making it to not do anything?

Comment: I don't think you have to worry about the cap. You have to find the exact difference with the external resistor, because it works when you do that. My guess is that it's parallel to the board resistor.

Comment: @LukeHappyValley yeah my bad

Comment: ESD damage is my guess - change the chip (pay attention to ESD).

Comment: I was grounded the whole time. I have 5 boards, I burn the first one (learning to solder SMD is tricky), but the other 4 works fine with the extra 10k resistor.

Comment: Seems a little bizarre to me. The datasheet says that _RST is a CMOS input with leakage current specified less than a microamp.

Comment: @Trunet - Hi, In response to the concern from *Andy aka* about possible ESD damage, you said: "*I was grounded the whole time*". FYI it is easily possible to cause ESD damage, even if *you* were grounded (e.g. using a wriststrap), depending on other factors including tools, equipment, clothing, environment & procedures. At this time of year in the northern hemispehere, reduced humidity also increases risks of ESD strikes. Due to insufficient info, I am *not* saying that ESD damage has definitely occurred. However reporting that you were grounded does *not* prove that ESD damage didn't occur.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the resistor to 4.7k and it's working now. Not sure why is that, but this solved it pulling RST up.

Answer (score 0):

You have not met the minimum voltage state for RST pin to be low.

See : https://somanytech.com/voltage-drop-across-resistor/ , particularly this part The voltage across series circuit- Practical examples:

Its been a while since i have done some EE experience

Comment: I didn't find the current needed on the RST pin in the datasheet to calculate the resistor.

Comment: any two equal resistors will give you half the voltage across them in series.But then again i could be wrong , little rusty here.

Comment: I'm aware of that. I will give it a try and replace the 10k with a 1k one and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a 10k-ish pull-down resistor internally or the internal protection diode got broken and acts like a resistor. This make me think "The higher the external pull-up resistance, the lower the RST pin voltage (Basic voltage divider)." And it worked after decreasing the PU resistance. Sounds reasonable, doesn't it?

I know, the datasheet does not show anything about that. But the behavior seems like there's an internal PD resistor or the protection diode failed.